# Piping stdout from a command to stdin of two commands in sh

Tags: unix, sh, ifconfig, egrep

tee [using >()] command is not working because it is not supported in sh (bourne shell).

What I am trying to achieve is sending the output of "ifconfig -a" to two different commands.

This is my command (which is clearly not right):

```
 ifconfig -a | egrep -o '255\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]' | egrep -o 'ff[[:xdigit:]]{6}'
```

I have tried other variants of this command, including the possibility of using tee, but it didn't seem to work, due to incompatibility with sh. It is necessary to stay with the lowest level of construct and that is why I am trying to make it work.

I know that on piping **egrep -o '255.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]'** I will get nothing but on piping **egrep -o 'ff[[:xdigit:]]{6}'** I will get my needed output (my netmask; that is a good regex for netmask), which is:

```
ff000000
fffff000
```

I am expecting it to give nothing on the first pipe and result on the second pipe but for that, both have the receive the stdout of "ifconfig -a".

I hope to receive some help. I am using /bin/sh, on FreeBSD (10.1; Amazon EC2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifconfig -a | egrep -o '255\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]|ff[[:xdigit:]]{6}'
```

If you also need results in a particular order, see `sort`

Comment: Pretty sweet; to the point. Sorting isn't an issue for now, however, I will try to implement that.